# Mapping array<number> into Promise array issue

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

My goal is to generate an array of Promises dynamically (by using Array.map()), and execute them at a posterior time.

```
export const ExecuteReader = async () => {
    let strAll = [1, 2].map((num) => testingFunction (num))
    //await Promise.all(strAll)

}

    export const testingFunction = (num) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('I have been called');
            resolve(1)
        }, 1000)

    })
}
```

ExecuteReader function is called by a "OnPress" event. (React-Native Touchable opacity.)

```
<TouchableOpacity
        onPress={async () => {
            await ExecuteReader().catch(err => console.log(err));
        }}>
        <Text>Click Me</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

To my understanding, the strAll Promise array should not execute its underlying functions, until it has been awaited ("Promise.All")
Im my case, it seems that the "testingFunction" prints out to console, while the "map" is iterating.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To my understanding, the strAll Promise array should not execute its underlying functions, until it has been awaited ("Promise.All")

That's incorrect, but you're not alone — it's a common misunderstanding. :-) Promises don't *do* anything, they're a way to observe and report on the completion of something else. When you call `new Promise`, the function you pass into it (the *promise executor*) is called right away, synchronously, to start the operation. Observing the promise via `then`, `catch`, etc. (directly or indirectly through `Promise.all`) doesn't make anything happen, it just hooks up handlers that will be called when whatever is already happening finishes (or if it's already done, will be called almost immediately [but still asynchronously]).

If you want to start those processes later, you need to delay your calls to `testingFunction`, since calling it starts the timer immediately.

Comment: FWIW, I go into promises in depth in Chapter 8 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if your'e interested.